# Get NFTs From a Collection in a wallet in js

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, nft, metaplex-js, candy-machine-v3

I have found many questions similar to this on stack exchange, But I have not found any working solution.
I want to Give the Public wallet address of a Solana wallet and Collection ID to code.
In Solely javascript by using Solana web3 js and metaplex js packages.
I tried Bard, GPT, and Stack Exchange stack overflow all, but I did Not find an appropriate solution for it to use in 2023 October (as of now). I need to use it in the browser later, but if I only find it to show in the node console I will modify the code on my own to browser compatibility. I will be thankful if someone can Give me this help. I think metaplex with web3 js will work if we use candy machine type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, Metaplex works. Metaplex has a JavaScript SDK for interacting with the program. Read more on the JavaScript SDK here https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/getting-started#javascript-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Alchemy works like a charm. I have used it for couple of projects and it returns all the wallet NFTs in Solana.
You can check here: https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-get-all-nfts-owned-by-an-address